# How to properly navigate an NLTK parse tree?

Tags: python, tree, nlp, nltk

NLTK is driving me nuts again.

How do I properly navigate through an NLTK tree (or ParentedTree)?
I would like to identify a certain leaf with the parent node "VBZ", then I would like to move from there further up the tree and to the left to identify the NP node.

How do I do this? The NLTK tree class does not seem to be thought through... Or I am too stupid...

Thanks for your help!

[image: Tree]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you want to do, this should work. It will give you the closest left NP node first, then the second closest, etc. So, if you had a tree of `(S (NP1) (VP (NP2) (VBZ)))`, your `np_trees` list would have `[ParentedTree(NP2), ParentedTree(NP1)]`.

```
from nltk.tree import *

np_trees = []

def traverse(t):
    try:
        t.label()
    except AttributeError:
        return

    if t.label() == "VBZ":
        current = t
        while current.parent() is not None:

            while current.left_sibling() is not None:

                if current.left_sibling().label() == "NP":
                    np_trees.append(current.left_sibling())

                current = current.left_sibling()

            current = current.parent()

    for child in t:
        traverse(child)

tree = ParentedTree.fromstring("(S (NP (NNP)) (VP (VBZ) (NP (NNP))))")
traverse(tree)
print np_trees # [ParentedTree('NP', [ParentedTree('NNP', [])])]
```

Comment: A very big thank you! I am still in the process of understanding what you did there.

Would it also be possible to look for a specific VBZ (with a certain leaf)?

As I cannot vote you up (I don't have enough reputation), can I buy you a coffee somehow?

Comment: By doing this, correct?
 
`if t.label() == "VBZ" and t.leaves()[0] == "does":`

(assuming "does" is the VBZ)

Comment: Tommy, how could I include the condition that the node underneath NP must be NNP? Your help would be much appreciated again!

Comment: I'll have to check the return value of `t.leaves()`, but if you want the VBZ to have only one leaf that is "does", assuming you get an array back from `leaves()` you should do this `and t.leaves() == ["does"]`. That'll take care of there being only the one word in the leaves without a possible index out of bounds exception in the case where there are no leaves. If there can be other leaves you might want to do `and "does" in t.leaves()` for the same reason

Comment: As for the NNP child, when you find the NP node, just check if the child(ren) of the NP node has a subtree rooted with a label of NNP. Depending on if there can only be a subtree with NNP or multiple subtrees and leaves in which one of them is NNP, how you search will vary a bit

Comment: And if you need me to comment my code to help you understand it, let me know and I'll edit my post